# Adding a "print agreement" button to the licence page in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I need help for putting a button (Print Agreement) on Inno Setup form to print EULA via printer.

During installation when the User Agreement page shows up there are 3 buttons (Back, Next and Cancel). I want to add one more button Print so user can print EULA document. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple script I put together that displays a **Print** button on the license screen and then opens Notepad with the license file which can be printed.

The `ShellExec` can be changed to the "Print" verb (shown in code but commented out) so that it can print to the default printer automatically.  That doesn't take into account systems with no printers installed though.  The code is:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{19ECF086-08A1-4A60-891F-E4D57E1266CF}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes   
LicenseFile=c:\license.txt

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\util\innosetup\Examples\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "c:\license.txt"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon


[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, "&", "&&")}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[code]
var PrintButton: TButton;

procedure PrintButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var ResultCode :integer;
begin
log('test');
ExtractTemporaryFile('license.txt');
//if not ShellExec('Print', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\license.txt'),
//     '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ResultCode) then
if not ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\license.txt'),
     '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ResultCode) then
log('test');
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
    PrintButton := TButton.Create(WizardForm);
    PrintButton.Caption := '&Print...';
    PrintButton.Left := WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Left + 96;
    PrintButton.Top := WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Height + 88;
    PrintButton.OnClick := @PrintButtonClick;
    PrintButton.Parent := WizardForm.NextButton.Parent;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPage: Integer);

begin
  PrintButton.Visible := CurPage = wpLicense;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks mirtheil...thanks a lot. After reading a script it looks so easy. :)

Comment: For an up-to-date version of this code, see [Adding a Print button to the License page in Inno Setup (revisited for Inno Setup 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69403271/850848).